# Exporting html table to pdf

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, html-table

What's wrong with my code ? I want to export my html table to pdf and save it. Then it so happened that it'll only open new browser with empty screen. Here is my sample code. Please do help.Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pdf">
<table id="StudentInfoListTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>    
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Track</th>
                    <th>S.S.C Roll</th>
                    <th>S.S.C Division</th>
                    <th>H.S.C Roll</th>
                    <th>H.S.C Division</th>
                    <th>District</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td>alimon  </td>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2222</td>
                        <td>as</td>
                        <td>3333</td>
                        <td>dd</td>
                        <td>33</td>
                    </tr>               
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

  <!--<button >Submit</button> -->
  <li> <a href="javascript:PrintDiv()">Export to pdf</a> </li>

<script type="text/javascript">     
    function PrintDiv(htmlexportPDF) {    
       var divToPrint = document.getElementById(htmlexportPDF);
       alert('Printing: Success');
       var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=650,height=600');
       popupWin.document.open();
       popupWin.document.write('<style type="text/css">body{ margin:0.5px;');
       popupWin.document.write('font-family:verdana,Arial;color:#000;');
       popupWin.document.write('font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:8px;}');
       popupWin.document.write('a{color:#000;text-decoration:none;}</style>');
       popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</html>');
       popupWin.document.close();
            }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript function printDiv takes in the parameter htmlexportPDF.

> function PrintDiv(htmlexportPDF) {

The problem is that when you called PrintDiv from your `<a>` link you didn't give any parameter.

To fix this, change

`<a href="javascript:PrintDiv()">Export to pdf</a>`

to

```
<a href="javascript:PrintDiv('StudentInfoListTable')">Export to pdf</a>
```

Also, in your HTML code, you never put an opening `<head>` tag or a closing `</body>` tag or a closing `</html>` tag.

Comment: Thank You. Sir :) Sorry for that closing </body> I missed to copy it :) Anyways it's a big help :)

Comment: The _tags_ for the `html`, `head` and `body` elements are (mostly) optional in HTML. _That_ part of the markup in the question is not wrong. The `li` element however, is out of place.